# comparing two hashmaps (same or different size) and storing the odd keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to compare two hashmap can be of same or different size.
1-store the key that are not present in both of the hashmaps.
2-store the key that are present in both hashmaps but have different values.

i have created a program that takes integers as input creates a hashmap with the integers associated with their frequency (no of occurences)

how can i store the hashmap keys that satisfies the above conditions

ex- arr={7 2 5 3 5 3}, brr={7 2 5 4 6 3 5 3} store=4,6

ex2- arr={203 204 205 206 207 208 203 204 205 206},  brr={203 204 204 205 206 207 205 208 203 206 205 206 204} store=204,205,206 since frequency doesnt match

my code is as-

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=s.nextInt();
    int[] arr=new int[x];
    int i,j,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
    arr[i]=s.nextInt(); 
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> check=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        check.put(arr[i], count);
        count=0;
    }
    int y=s.nextInt();
    int[] brr=new int[y];
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
    brr[i]=s.nextInt(); 
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> check1=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int count1=0;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            if(brr[i]==brr[j])
            {
                count1++;
            }
        }
        check1.put(brr[i], count1);
        count1=0;
    }
    System.out.println(check);
    System.out.println(check1);
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: the question is how can i store the hashmap keys that satisfies the above conditions

Comment: We won't do your homework. You need to try something.

Comment: Its not a homework i found this problem in a text book and got stuck in last.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Try something, show what you tried, and precisely tell what you expect the code to do and what it does instead.

Comment: sir, the code above i posted is what i tried it takes the two array as input creates a hashmap with their associated frequencys what i am unable to figure out is how can i store the odd values(with above two conditions);

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) there are `Sets.symmetricDifference()` and `Sets.intersection()`.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> a = Map.of(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2); // {2=2, 1=1, 0=0}
Map<Integer, Integer> b = Map.of(0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 8); // {4=8, 2=4, 0=0}

Set<Integer> differentKeys = Sets.symmetricDifference(a.keySet(), b.keySet());
System.out.println(differentKeys); // [1, 4]

Set<Integer> sameKeyDifferentValues = Sets.intersection(a.keySet(), b.keySet())
        .stream()
        .filter(c -> !a.get(c).equals(b.get(c)))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(sameKeyDifferentValues); // [2]
```

Comment: Is there an alternate for guava i want to use java built in librarys

Comment: i have figured out the solution and m posting it so that it could help sombody later..ArrayList<Integer> store=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int key:check1.keySet())
  {
   if(check.containsKey(key))
   {
    int valb=check.get(key);
    int vala=check1.get(key);
    if(vala-valb!=0)
    {
     store.add(key);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    store.add(key);
   }
  }
  //Collections.sort(store);
  for(i=0;i<store.size();i++)
  {
   System.out.print(store.get(i)+" ");
  }